# Undefined entries in an array return `true` after parsing them as boolean with `every`

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, undefined

To keep track of 3 booleans, I decided to use a simple array:

```
var processingDone = Array(3);
```

Then, I'd just set the booleans at the proper index (pseudo code):

```
function stepTwoDone(){
    processingDone[1] = true;
}
```

I figured an easy way to check if all of the booleans in there were true, would be to use `every`, like this:

```
if(processingDone.every(Boolean)){
    // Do stuff
}
```

Now, for some reason, if not all of the booleans are set, but all the booleans that *are* set, are `true`, the `every` returns `true`:

```js
alert('Array(3): '     + Array(3).every(Boolean) + '\n' +         // true
      '[,,]: '         + [,,].every(Boolean) + '\n' +             // true
      '[true,,true]: ' + [true,,true].every(Boolean) + '\n' +     // true
      '[,false,]: '    + [,false,].every(Boolean) + '\n' +        // false
      'All true: '     + [true,true,true].every(Boolean) + '\n' + // true
      'All false: '    + [false,false,false].every(Boolean));     // false
```

---

**So, what's going on here?**
Why does an undefined value in the array appear to equal a truthy value, when passed to the `Boolean` constructor? Simply calling `Boolean()` without parameter returns `false`, as expected...

---

Of course, and easy solution would be to just set the values to something falsy in the first place:

```
var processingDone = [false, false, false];
```

Comment: If an index isn't initialized (or deleted) it's `undefined` and therefore ignored by `.every()`. It's step 7.b/c from here [ECMAScript, 15.4.4.16 Array.prototype.every](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.16)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDN on `forEach`

> forEach executes the provided callback once for each element present
>   in the array in ascending order. It is **not** invoked for indexes **that
>   have been deleted or elided**. However, it is executed for elements that
>   are present and **have the value undefined**.

I strongly suspect `every` is also looped this way, though I'm searching for the spec.

So, when `[true,,true]` calls `every`, only `[true,true]`(say), gets passed as the second element is ignored. However consider the below

```
[true,undefined,true].every(Boolean) // false
```

The above returns `false` as **it actually contains** the value `undefined`, and not just mere result of `undefined` which is what we get when we try to access element of an array with an index which is not yet set.

In our case, `[true,,true]` has values in 0 and 2 index but doesn't in 1

### Summary:

Boolean(or callback specified) only gets called for actual values that are present and not for those which result in a *falsey* value (`undefined`) because they don't exist in the first place.

[ECMAScript Language Specification - ECMA-262 Edition 5.1 also suggests the same](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.16)

Comment: It would certainly make sense for that to be the case, here. [@Andreas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas)' [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941288/unexpected-behavior-in-empty-arrays-with-a-set-length#comment44278813_27941288) seems to confirm this.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks for the link. Thanks to Andreas too.

Answer (score 2):

This is how array.every works:

- the callback gets called for every array element that has assigned values, it does NOT get called for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values ( eg. your Array(3) )
- it will return false if the callback returned a false value. Because you did not assign values, Boolean never gets called.

Try it

```
[false,false,false].every(function(value) {
  console.info(arguments); 
  return true;
});
```

vs. (no console output)

```
Array(3).every(function(value) {
  console.info(arguments); 
  return true;
});
```